# Convert float[][] to grayscale image

Tags: java, image-processing

I have float[][] where each member has a value in [0..1]

This represents a pixel map of a greyscale image.

How can I convert the float to RGB value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Do you want to convert a grayscale image into a colour image? Or just have it in RGB still representing a grayscale one?

Comment: Yes leave it be grayscale. 0 - white, 1 - black and all what is in the middle is kind of gray. I need it in RGB.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry saw your edit now.

Comment: If you know enough to say you want an RGB value, why are you wasting people's time asking how to divide n/255 and truncate the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing to remember is that in a grey RGB image, the Red Green and Blue pixel values are all the same.

So, take each pixel and multiply it by 255 and make an integer of it, then store it as a PPM file, which has a really simple format described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_anymap).

Basically, if your float pixel is 0.5 you will get 127 and will then write this 3 times (once for red, once for green and once for blue) into your PPM file. The header at the start is dead simple, just

```
P6
<columns> <rows>
255
RGBRGBRGRGBRGBRGB...
```

Once you have a PPM image you can use ImageMagick or Photoshop to convert it to JPEG or PNG or whatever you like.

It would be faster and take only a third of the space if you used a ".pgm" extension, saved the first line as "P5" rather than "P6" and only wrote each pixel once rather than repeating the value 3 times for R, G and B.... but you wanted RGB.